# Обрезаются названия товаров в магазине

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет-магазин на WordPress WooCommerce. На главной странице в перечне товаров текст в ссылке выводится почему-то таким образом:

```
<div class="product-section">
    <h3>
        <a href="../vkusnye-rebryshki-nyam-nyam-3/">Вкусные ребрыш�...</a>
    </h3>
</div>
```

Некоторые названия выводятся хорошо: "Гриль из курицы", а часть в таком виде: "Стейк из свинин..." Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Быстрее всего у Вас там при виводе товара работает функция substr().

Comment: strlen('Гриль из курицы') == 28, strlen('Стейк из свинины') == 30, strlen('Вкусные ребрышки') == 31. Так что никакой загадки здесь нет. Проблема видна только когда обрезается на пол-буквы, это зависит от строки. В вашем случае страдают строки с одним пробелом ))) Скорее всего в выводе обрезка выглядит так: substr($str, 0, 28)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

откопал строчку в файле content-product.php и заменил вывод с

```
<?php echo mad_post_content_truncate(get_the_title(), 28, '.', '...' ); ?>
```

на

```
<?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
```

Может быть кому-нить пригодится. Вопрос решен!

Comment: То есть "28" всё-таки присутствовало! :) Я бы таки нашел где объявлена функция mad_post_content_truncate и **там** заменил substr на mb_substr.

Comment: @artoodetoo так все равно же будет обрезать название? а мне нужно, чтобы оно полностью выводилось, даже, если и на 3 строки

Comment: Ну это дело хозяйское! Я подумал, что наверное там обрезка не просто так стояла, а ради сохранения дизайна, например. Только с мультибайтными символами накосячили.

Answer (score 2):

Где-то, скорее всего в шаблоне вывода, стоит обрезание строки. Западные разрабочики не всегда помнят про то, что есть алфавиты кроме латинского. В кодировке UTF-8 такие буквы кодируются 2 - 4 байтами (символы кириллицы — два байта). Поэтому случется обрезание "на полбуквы".

Вызовы **substr** необходимо найти и заменить на мультибайтную **[mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-substr.php)**. Найти нужное место можно по фрагменту, который находится рядом и не меняется от записи к записи. В вашем случае можно искать `<div class="product-section">` и где-то рядом с ним обнаружится substr().

И наверняка уже существует исправленный вариант, погуглите что-то вроде "woocommerce русский".

Comment: но там сотни файлов для замены, а плагин Advanced Excerpt не работает.. или нужно заново создать товары, чтобы увидеть результат?

Comment: Нет, не думаю что товары надо заново создавать. Скорее всего это проблема Вывода, а не хранения. Проверить-то нетрудно, правда?

Comment: я уже проверил - это проблема вывода, да.. как же ее цивилизовано решить?

Comment: Цивилизованно — это как, чтобы без труда? Как минимум, придется поискать уже локализованную версию плагина и переставить его. Ну или поискать число 28 и посмотреть не подставляется ли оно в функцию substr. Куда уж проще!

Comment: не прокатило.. в единственном файле config.php, где есть <div class="product-section"> заменил все вхождения substr на mb_substr, и даже strlen на mb_strlen - не помогло...

Comment: а как вообще запретить обрезание названия? так, чтобы, если не вмещается в одну строку - выводилось все на второй?

Comment: Легко! Надо сказать "эй, ты, прекрати обрезать мои данные". А конкретно: надо найти нужное место и убрать substr )))

Comment: т.е. вот с этой строчкой поиграться?
"$post_content = !empty($product->post->post_excerpt) ? $product->post->post_excerpt : mb_substr($product->post->post_content, 0, 200) . '...';"
изменить на "$post_content = $product->post->post_excerpt;
? нет, не выходит..

Comment: Нет. Из предыдущих сообщений выходило, что обрезание делается НЕ-мультибайтной функцией substr(). И притом скорее всего на 28 символов, никак не на 200. Если концепция уже изменилась, то я не знаю…

Comment: если я включаю поиск по цифре 28 - ничего в файлах не находит..